# How to use VS Code to debug JavaScript within HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, browser, vscode-debugger

How do I set up Visual Studio Code to debug with breakpoints a JavaScript file which is part of an HTML file?

What I want to accomplish is demonstrated in this video, but it doesn't explain how to set it up:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ub2GCC8DHg&t=190s

*Edit:*

**What the video shows:**
The video shows a JavaScript program (and the HTML file it's attached to) running in Microsoft Edge browser. The JavaScript is being debugged in VS Code with breakpoints. The browser pauses when a break point is reached. Then the browser resumes when the JavaScript resumes running after the break point.

**What I've tried:**
I've installed VS Code and I'm able to debug standalone (not part of an HTML file) JavaScript with break points. When it comes to running JavaScript that's part of an HTML file, I can run the files in a web browser by pasting into it the file path of the HTML file. I'm also able to run the files with an extension called Live Preview by Microsoft. The JavaScript and HTML files run fine together without errors in my browser.

**Where I'm stuck:**
There is no sync between the browser and VS Code. When I try to debug the JavaScript, it doesn't know it's part of the HTML. It is debugged as standalone, so there's an error because it needs the DOM object from the HTML file.

Comment: Please explain, in words, what you have tried and where you are stuck. A video does not help people who are blind or visually impaired (or audibly impaired for that matter) or people who are unable to access YouTube for other reasons. Questions and answers should be able to stand on their own. See [ask] for more.

Comment: Ok. I've added more details in the EDIT section.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No matter how well he would have phrased his question, if you are blind and deaf you're not going to be able to read it regardless. What a strange correction, and I know why you said it that way, and so do you.

Comment: @Postermaestro If the OP writes the question correctly, there are devices that can help turn the text into something intelligible by the user (e.g., braille screen readers for those who are blind and deaf). Not so if it is locked behind a video or image. I'm not sure why empathy is so strange to you...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Your high horse attitude truly is appalling. It's rampant on this forum unfortunately.

Comment: Are there blind or deaf people that use VS Code? If there are, then I can see how summarizing the video content is helpful.